# Clear color in CIWarpKernel

Tags: core-image, ciwarpkernel

I have a warp kernel, that I want to be able to return clear color for some coordinates, similar to a discardFragment in fragment shaders.

If I just return the coordinates that are outside the image extent it works as expected when rendered to a MTKView (I can see clear pixels). OTOH when rendering to a bitmap, the pixels that are supposed to be clear take the color of the nearest edge (similar to when sampling clampedToExtent).

There's an option to rewrite warp kernel into a generic CIKernel and return clear color from there, but we're loosing benefits of warp kernel simplicity and under-the-hood optimizations.

---

I can also think of this solution:

1. Overlay input image over a larger black image
2. Crop back to original extent after applying the effect

This would require to change the kernel logic to take extra edge size into account

---

Is there simpler, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this?

Comment: No, not really. I ended up doing a workaround as in the question..